# Update List of objects in Room with another list from Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a list of objects (each one represents the metadata of a file), and I keep this list in a table using Room, to consult the data when offline. Every time the app starts and a network connection is available, Retrofit downloads the updated list of files, and I have to update the list in the DB.

- a first, naive strategy would be to simply nuke the table and write every entry again, regardless of the already stored entries. This is clearly not optimal
- a second approach would be to build a list of removed entries and a list of added entries, with the updated entries in both the lists.

I'm using a helper class to do this, how can I optimize this process?

Main class

```
        val filesManager = filesManager(appContext)
        filesManager.compareEntries(remoteEntries, viewModel.fileEntries)
```

I'm using the first approach at the moment, and the file entries are taken from a static (non-live data) query on the DB. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check the Paging Library documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)

Even if your use case may not be precisely paging, you'll find while going through that document (and the provided samples) good guidance that applies to any Server + DB data architecture.

Things like defining a unique source of truth, when the data is considered expired, and what triggers a refresh of new data you'll be able to find there. This may lead you to the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly i only have a couple of Retrofit calls and nothing more, so i'm trying to understand the best practice in those cases, if it exists. Of couse a socket or something similar would have been a better solution, but i have no control over that. For a small amount of updates the first strategy could be enough, but i'm not sure. Anyway, i'll surely take a look at the guide, thanks again!